# Как в django загружать файл на сервер? Ошибка: IntegrityError at /upload/ NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

Tags: django

**При загрузке получаю ошибку**

Я так понимаю модели не хватает id пользователя, но где его не хватает, не могу понять. Django вроде делает всю работу за меня))

> IntegrityError at /upload/
>       NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.author_id

**Обработчик загрузки** (views.py)

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**Модель** (models.py)

```
SCRIPT_TYPE = (
    ('SINGLE', 'SINGLE'),
    ('MULTI', 'MULTI'),
)


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', null=False, verbose_name="Автор", )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, verbose_name="Заголовок", )
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SCRIPT_TYPE, default='MULTI', null=False, verbose_name="Тип", )
    text = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name="Описание", )
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Дата создания", )
    script = models.FileField(null=False, blank=True, upload_to="scripts/", verbose_name="Скрипт", )

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**HTML файл**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main_window.css' %}">

</head>
<body>
<h1>New post</h1>

<form method="post" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка сообщает вам, что при сохранении не было установлено обязательное поле `author` модели `Post`. Судя по всему, вы хотите, чтобы в этом поле хранился тот пользователь, который нажал на кнопку "Save" в форме. Сделать это можно так:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def model_form_upload(request):
    ...
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.author = request.user
    post.save()
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))